# JavaScript promises between function 'class' wrappers

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to promises and would like to solve following scenario:

Consider a main 'class' function `Main()` that represents a three.js-Scene and a 'sub-class' function `Sub()` that represents data to render:

- `Main()` has a method `addSubDataToObject()` that invokes `new
  Sub()` into an `Main().data` object (`{id_x: data_from_url_x}`)
- `Main()` has another method `renderDataObjects()` to render the data
  (via three.js `addToScene()`)
- `Sub()` retrieves remote data via method `getData()` on invoke
  (calling a WebWorker using `XMLHttpRequest`) and processes it to be returned as an object (`{id: data_from_url}`)

After invoking

```
var main = new Main();
```

I´d like to be able to add multiple data objects

```
main.addSubDataToObject(id_1, url_1);
main.addSubDataToObject(id_2, url_2);
```

and call

```
main.renderDataObject();
```

to render each object in `main.data` to the scene when all data calls finished downloading and processing.
Currently I use a callback to add each data call to the scene when each has finished

```
main.addSubDataToObject(id_1, url_1, cb);
main.addSubDataToObject(id_1, url_2, cb);
```

but this, of course, adds them subsequentially and with a delay based on the payload.

I thought, for example, to make `Main()`'s `.addSubDataToObject()` to return a promise each into an array of promises and `.renderDataObject()` with `Promise.all()` to await to resolve all of them before rendering.
However, I don't get how to implement this in conjunction with the data object(s) and how to handle the 'class' objects with promises. If possible (and this seems practical to you), I would much appreciate an example structure for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you just want to know how to work with Promises inside of a class function? Is this what you're looking for?

```
class Main {
  renderDataObject(data) {
    /* data will be an array of all resolvedData in the order they were resolved */
  }

  addSubDataToObject(id, url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // do work

      resolve(/* resolvedData? */);
    });
  }
}

let main = new Main();
let promises = [];

promises.push(main.addSubDataToObject(id_1, url_1));
promises.push(main.addSubDataToObject(id_2, url_2));

Promise.all(promises).then(main.renderDataObject);
```

Comment: absolutely almost ,) I would like to have the promise logic wrapped in .renderDataObject(). Would this be as easy as adding the promises array as a class variable, fill it from within .addSubDataObject(id, url) (promises.push() instead of return?) and have Promise.all(Main.promises) inside .renderDataObject() execute with .then(*loop_through_data_array*)? (I can´t try myself untill tomorrow...)

Comment: update: I tested and it's just that easy! thanks for this exact amount of good info that let me figure out the last cosmetic changes!